# Angular Table Row Animation

Tags: angularjs, animation

What is the best way to highlight a row for a few seconds when it is updated but then return to whatever background color that row was previously? I have been trying to use jquery .animate to do it but it doesn't seem to recognize the dynamic content being added from angular. I want to make it so when I edit an item and the table updates with the new values the row highlights for a few seconds to make picking out the updates easier for the user. If someone could provide a small plunker example that would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a some code and people will gladly help. You should show what you have have so far and what doesn't work. People aren't here to really write all your code for you. :( .
But to answer your question more directly: There are existing libraries out there that can do just that Dojo's DGrid, jQuery's Datatables, SlickGrid, and many more. But you can achieve the same by adding a class to your row after an event ( like a button click ) and then do $timeout that removes that class. This class could potentially change the background color.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qcsmas3n/1/ I put together a little something